# how to create vertical slider in android by @react-native-community/slider?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, slider, vertical-alignment

[image]
As the title and picture, how to create vertical slider in android by @react-native-community/slider?
I try to create a slider like: `<Slider vertical={true}/>` but it's not working.

Comment: so what is not working? can you share your example?

Comment: I follow this https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider#vertical but slider is not vertical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching, I finally found a solution
Use transform css to rotate 90deg component  https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms

Answer (score 5):

The vertical prop is for windows only. It is not available for android or IOS.
If u want to vertically rotate it you can wrap the slider inside View and rotate the View:

```
<View style={{transform:[{rotate: "-90deg"}]}}>
 <Slider ... />
</View>
```

Comment: that's f***ed up